# Workflow or process builder Not working with Communities developed with napili page and custom Lightning Component

Tags: community, napili

I just update a record of custom object ,to trigger a workflow .
the DML is roll backed due to the below error.

> FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error.

And also when i deactivate the workflow the record is update.
I have also tried with process builder,wherein am getting error:

> Maximum stack depth reached:2.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. The flow works correctly when fired from an internal record update, but when the record update originates from a lightning component in a community, the flow fails with `Maximum stack depth reached:2`.